# How to sort pods with respect to their IPs

Tags: kubernetes

How to sort the pods with respect to it's IP or it's Node IP.

I tried this command and I have around 20 pods running on my 3 node cluster.

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --sort-by={'.spec.ip'}
```

> error: ip is not found

this is the error I am getting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong command to sort. The correct command will be:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --sort-by={.status.podIP}
```

This will sort your pods according to the podIP.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `sorter.go:349] couldn't find any field with path "{.status.podIP}" in the list of objects` But it works for other items like `.status.startTime`. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Could you please run the command with `-o json` and check if the `.status.podIP` exists?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [kubesort](https://github.com/AATHITH/kubesort) to simplify sorting. It may help you.